# Tensflow Keras: TypeError: can't pickle _thread.RLock objects when using multiprocessing

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, multiprocessing, tensorflow2.0

I have raised this issue in GitHub: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/46917

I am trying to use multiprocessing threads to speedup the some of my code. In which I have to send a Keras model to each thread and use it to predict on some inputs and do some following computations. However, I end up with the following error

```
Tensflow Keras: TypeError: can't pickle _thread.RLock objects
```

I tried,

1. using `partial` to fix the model argument and use the resulting partial-function.
2. cloning the model and using a clone for each thread
3. saving and reloading a model for each thread
4. tried using `pathos.multiprocessing`
   but none of them worked.

The following is the MWE

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
import numpy as np


from multiprocessing import Pool
# from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool as ThreadPool
# from pathos.multiprocessing import ProcessingPool as Pool
from functools import partial


def simple_model():
    model = keras.models.Sequential([
        keras.layers.Dense(units = 10, input_shape = [1]),
        keras.layers.Dense(units = 1, activation = 'sigmoid')
    ])
    model.compile(optimizer = 'sgd', loss = 'mean_squared_error')
    return model

def clone_model(model):
    model_clone = tf.keras.models.clone_model(model)
    model_clone.set_weights(model.get_weights())
    model_clone.build((None, 1))
    model_clone.compile(optimizer = 'sgd', loss = 'mean_squared_error')
    return model_clone

def work(model, seq):
    return model.predict(seq)

def load_model(model_savepath):
    return tf.keras.models.load_model(model_savepath)

def worker(model, n = 4):
    seqences = np.arange(0,100).reshape(n, -1)
    pool = Pool()
    model_savepath = './simple_model.h5'
    model.save(model_savepath)
    model_list = [load_model(model_savepath) for _ in range(n)]
    # model_list = [clone_model(model) for _ in range(n)]
    results = pool.map(work, zip(model_list,seqences))
    # partial_work = partial(work, model=model)
    # results = pool.map(partial_work, seqences)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
    
    return np.reshape(results, (-1, ))



if __name__ == '__main__':

    model = simple_model()
    out = worker(model, n=4)
    print(out)
```

This results in the following error trace:

```
File "c:/Users/***/Documents/GitHub/COVID-NSF/test4.py", line 42, in <module>
  out = worker(model, n=4)
File "c:/Users/****/Documents/GitHub/COVID-NSF/test4.py", line 30, in worker
  results = pool.map(work, zip(model_list,seqences))
File "C:\Users\****\anaconda3\envs\tf-gpu\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 268, in map
  return self._map_async(func, iterable, mapstar, chunksize).get()
File "C:\Users\****\anaconda3\envs\tf-gpu\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 657, in get
  raise self._value
File "C:\Users\***\anaconda3\envs\tf-gpu\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 431, in _handle_tasks
  put(task)
File "C:\Users\***\anaconda3\envs\tf-gpu\lib\multiprocessing\connection.py", line 206, in send
  self._send_bytes(_ForkingPickler.dumps(obj))
File "C:\Users\***\anaconda3\envs\tf-gpu\lib\multiprocessing\reduction.py", line 51, in dumps
  cls(buf, protocol).dump(obj)
TypeError: can't pickle _thread.RLock objects
```

Comment: As the github user amahendrakar stated in the issue you raised, you cannot pass a model to a child process. You must call `load_model` from the child process either with an initialization function in the `Pool` constructor, or in the `work` function

Comment: @Aaron I posted the solution based on your comments.

Answer (score 0):

@Aaron thanks for explaining the comment made by amahendrakar on GitHub. I modified the code such that the code sends the path of the model, rather than the model itself, to the child processes. Below is the working code

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
import numpy as np


# from multiprocessing import Pool
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool as ThreadPool
from pathos.multiprocessing import ProcessingPool as Pool
from functools import partial
import time

def simple_model():
    model = keras.models.Sequential([
        keras.layers.Dense(units = 10, input_shape = [1]),
        keras.layers.Dense(units = 1, activation = 'sigmoid')
    ])
    model.compile(optimizer = 'sgd', loss = 'mean_squared_error')
    return model

def clone_model(model):
    model_clone = tf.keras.models.clone_model(model)
    model_clone.set_weights(model.get_weights())
    model_clone.build((None, 1))
    model_clone.compile(optimizer = 'sgd', loss = 'mean_squared_error')
    return model_clone

def work(model, seq):
    return model.predict(seq)

def work_new(seq):
    model_savepath = './simple_model.h5'
    model = tf.keras.models.load_model(model_savepath)
    return model.predict(seq)

def load_model(model_savepath):
    return tf.keras.models.load_model(model_savepath)

def worker(model, n = 4):
    seqences = np.arange(0,10*n).reshape(n, -1)
    pool = Pool()
    model_savepath = './simple_model.h5'
    model.save(model_savepath)
    # model_list = [load_model(model_savepath) for _ in range(n)]
    # model_list = [clone_model(model) for _ in range(n)]
    # results = pool.map(work, zip(model_list,seqences))
    # path_list = [[model_savepath] for _ in range(n)]
    # print(np.shape(path_list), np.shape(seqences))
    # work_new_partial = partial(work_new, path=model_savepath)
    results = pool.map(work_new,  seqences)
    # partial_work = partial(work, model=model)
    # results = pool.map(partial_work, seqences)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
    # print(t1-t0)
    return np.reshape(results, (-1, ))



if __name__ == '__main__':

    model = simple_model()
    t0 = time.perf_counter()
    out = worker(model, n=40)
    t1 = time.perf_counter()

    # print(out)
    print(f"time taken {t1 - t0}")
```

This results in

```
time taken 8.521342800000001
```